# Azure AD to authenticate to on-premises applications (token transformation service and similar)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to get Azure AD to be the Identity Provider for corporate users to authenticate to AAD and access on-premises applications from home, from a corporate-owned virtual (and physical) desktop, preferably using SSO, and optional MFA. The on-premises applications require one or more of Kerberos, OIDC, and SAML tokens/tickets. Currently, Hybrid AD Connect is enabled. It is likely that a token transformation service would be required for at least some applications. Assume that the corporate devices may not necessarily be part of the internal network all the time.

Looking for suggestions on standard solution patterns, including third party and open-source products.

Comment: Are the on-premise applications Web Apps or also desktop apps?

Comment: They are a mix of Web and Desktop apps, i.e. some require Kerberos or its Unix variant, others require SAML or OIDC etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your environment has hybrid setup which includes On-premises Active Directory setup and Azure AD setup also which is synced from on premises to Azure through Azure Active Directory Connect tool. In this scenario, to implement a token transformation service which provisions SSO through modern authentication protocols like SAML, OAuth tokens, MFA and others, setting up an ADFS Server on premises is the best option as it will federate with multiple SaaS platforms by creating relying party trusts and help with SSO in different scenarios. Enable it to be exposed over the internet either via a firewall or a web application proxy so that it can receive authentication requests. You would need to buy a public certificate to use with ADFS for service communication and a public domain to use with the same. ADFS 2019 supports OpenID, OAuth, SAML protocols etc. For the applications that use Kerberos in on prem environment, it will work normally. Anything that use OAuth, OpenID can be integrated with ADFS and added to it as a relying party app. ADFS can be federated with Office 365/Azure AD. You can either use the Connect-MsolService module to setup federation on ADFS or use the AAD connect in order to manage or setup Federation using Azure AD connect. If the user can be external to company network then I would suggest to use Conditional access capabilities that you can get if you already have Azure AD premium license or EMS license in order to secure access to your applications.

However, as mentioned above, ADFS Federation service would always have an external public facing web application proxy endpoint where any application which is accessible through the internet can reach and remote users can work without the need to VPN into the corporate network. However, if Azure AD application proxy is not needed in your case as you do not have any application published over the open internet, then you will have to use VPN.

Also, find the below documentation link of Windows ADFS latest features for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/whats-new-active-directory-federation-services-windows-server

I hope this provides you with enough clarifications for your query.

Thanks,